# jQuery: Iterate Through a Limited Array of Numeric Values On Click

Tags: jquery, arrays, variables

I know it's a very basic question, but still:

When a page is first loaded, the variable **myvar** is set to a random value: 0, 1, 2, or 3.

On button click, if the variable is less than 3, it's incremented by 1. If the variable = 3, it's set to 0.

Would be grateful for help form an jQuery expert!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/67YP9/2/)**

```
<input type="button" id="buttonId" value="click me" />

$('#buttonId').click(function(){
     // myvar = 3;
     if(myvar < 3)
         myvar++;
     if(myvar ==3)
         myvar = 0;
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is just what I was looking for. I have q question to you: how can I pass these values to a PHP variable $my_var?

Comment: You can save in hidden field and access it on postback, or use jquery ajax for asynchronous call.

Comment: I'm sorry, @Adil, could you show me how to do that, please? Basically, I need to pass values 0 to 3 to a MySQL query, on click.

Comment: I think this shows how you can do it, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8741517/set-hidden-field-value-using-javascript-use-php-post-method-to-send-the-data

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
$('#button').click(function(){
    if (myvar< 3){
        myvar++;
    }else{
        myvar = 1;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#button').click(function(){
    myvar = (myvar == 3) ? 0 :  ++myvar;
    }
});
```